# TypeScript function returns multiple options

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, es6-promise

I have a function as below and I can't wrap my head around it.  How can a function return multiple types and how are each used?

```
function(): Observable<Type> | Promise<Type> | Type {
...
}
```

It looks like the pipe(|) is used to designate that multiple values can be returned.  What I don't understand is when is each used?  I suspect that the Observable is used when a `subscribe` is issued, the Promise is used by default, and the straight up Type is used when the function is called with `await`.

If I'm right, great!  I can't seem to find documentation for this functionality so that I can learn more.  Can you help?  I suspect my issue is that I don't know what to Google search for.

*UPDATE: Additional Code Sample*

The following is a code sample where multiple return types are provided, but I only return the boolean type.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) :
      Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
          .then((authenticated: boolean) => {
            if (authenticated) {
              return true;
            } else {
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
          });
        }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) :
      Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
      }


}
```

What is determining whether to return the `Type` as is, versus wrapping this in a Promise or Observable (for subscription)?

Comment: It has one return type, but that return type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) of 3 other types, e.g. the range of values described by type `string | number` includes values like `"foo"` and `123`.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. The function should always return a promise or always return an observable (depending on what you need).

Comment: Thank you for the link @p.s.w.g!  I read through the union docs and I finally can see some of what's going on.  What I don't get is that in a signature like I show above, I can just return the `Type` type and somehow it magically will make it a Observable or a Promise when called within an `async` function or `subscribe`d to.  This leads me to believe that there is some magic going on within Typescript or Javascript to wrap that returned variable.  I'll update my question with another code sample.

Comment: @BK- No it won't magically make it observable. It means that whatever code calls this function must run type checks on its return value to ensure that it's actually an `Observable<T>`, etc. This is why Bergi pointed out that it's generally a bad idea (it means you can't actually trust the return type value that much). In this case, it means that whatever uses `CanActivate`/`CanActivateChild` **must** be coded in such a way to account for this variance.

Comment: Oh interesting!  Thanks for the follow-up!  Is there any way to determine how the function was called so that the appropriate return value can be returned?  For example, can I tell if the caller wants a promise versus just the value?

Comment: BTW one of the core design principles behind TypeScript is that it doesn't do any magic (at runtime, at least -- see [point 6 under non-goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals)). It's purely used to describe what *can* be returned from this function and still be a valid program. There is no way for the caller cannot tell this function what it wants. Instead it is forced to just deal with whatever the this function gives it.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you, this makes much more sense.  Now to track down the sample code's author...

Comment: Here's a perfect real-world example of an interface that returns multiple types.  It seems to infer that either return type can be returned and the caller will know what to do with this?  https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside your function body you will decide when to return which type of result. When you use the return value you do not know directly the type of the result. Therefor you can `cast` the result:

```
function a(foo: string): string | boolean {
  if (foo) return true
  return "my string value"
}
const b = (a("") as boolean)
const c = (a("hello") as string)
```

In this case `b` would be `typeof boolean` while `c` is a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**

There is no way to tell which type is returned in which scenario. That's because the only thing that matters to TypeScript is that the type returned in your function body is assignable to the one used in its definition.

Consider this silly example:

```
function foo(): string | number | boolean {
    return 0;
}
```

On the type level, there is nothing wrong with this function. There is no way in the world it's going to return `string | boolean`, but it doesn't matter. What matters is that `0` is assignable to `string | number | boolean`.

**What you can do**

You can delete the return type definition and see what is the inferred return type.

Comment: Scary!  0, true, "true", and "0" all being `true` is too much like PERL.